# Dynamics 365 Portals - Default language

Tags: dynamics-crm, adxstudio-portals, dynamics-crm-portals, powerapps-portal

We use Dynamics 365 Portals with 2 languages (fr-FR / en-US).
We have 3 websites, and we remark that when accessing 2 websites with their urls, the browser add systematically the language to the URL : https://url**/fr-FR**, but for the 3rd website, the language is not added to the url.

Did we miss any configuration in the 3rd Website that avoid the browser to add the language code to the URL ?

Thanks.

Comment: I believe you already added default language to the 3rd website. Just take a look at doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/portals/configure/enable-multiple-language-support)

Comment: It was already populated, but when I verified the language, I found that it was deactivated.
I modified the default language by an activated one, and all seems OK.
Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Cool, I will add my comment as answer. Please mark it as solved.